# TableChart in GAS, what are the different options for setOptions()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I can't find an exhaustive list.

I'm trying to set the font size on a TableChart, but can't figure out how or if it's even possible. Searching the internet yielded no source of information on the different options available.

I know you can do the following:

```
setOption('height' : '100%')
```

for example, but

```
setOption('font-size' : '16pt')
```

and

```
setOption('fontSize' : '16pt')
```

Don't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, unfortunately. I've tried to style my Table Charts as well, but ended up going with a FlexTable for some of it.

The options are listed in [the documentation for the Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options), which the Charts Service uses (and the [Apps Script documentation mentions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/table-chart-builder#setOption%28String,Object%29)).